# Getting error converting .tif to .map format?

Tags: qgis, gdal-translate

I am getting this error when I try to convert .tif to .map format:

> ERROR 6: PCRaster driver: Cannot convert cells: Usetype is not version
>   2 cell representation, VS_LDD or VS_BOOLEAN  Input file size is 2240,
>   2160.

How do I deal with it?

Comment: Show the gdal command that QGIS creates. What do you mean with .map format? The one used by Ozi Explorer or what?

Comment: Please edit your question and include either a `gdalinfo` report for the tif, or the details in the information section of the QGIS layer properties (please use text formatted as code using the `{ }` button, not screenshots)